# I am using Turtle and when I open a window with Turtle, it does not respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am using Turtle and when I open a window with Turtle, it does not respond. I haven't finished the code yet. I am still a beginner and I am trying to make a simple pong game. Thanks!

```
import turtle

# Paddles
pa = turtle.Turtle()
pa.speed(0)
pa.shape("square")
pa.color("white")
pa.penup()
pa.goto(-350, 0)
pa.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)

pb = turtle.Turtle()
pb.speed(0)
pb.shape("square")
pb.color("white")
pb.penup()
pb.goto(350, 0)
pb.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)

# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
# Screen
win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Stankity Stank Stank Stank")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)
while True:
    win.update

# Controls
def paup():
    y = pa.ycor()
    y += 20
    pa.sety(y)

win.listen()
win.onkeypress(paup, "w")
```

Stack Overflow said my post was mostly code, so here's some extra text.

Comment: See the [mcve] guidelines. Provide us with the *shortest possible code* that results in your problem. Also, `win.update` is not `win.update()`, and because you've got that in a `while True:` loop, `win.listen()` is never called, and neither is `win.onkeypress(paup, "w")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You did not ask a question.  I presume it is "Why don't I see anything?" Answers:

1. A white pen on a white background is invisible.
2. A pen that is up does not draw.

Fix those two things and the following draws a black line with a square at the end.

```
import turtle

pb = turtle.Turtle()
pb.speed(0)
pb.shape("square")
pb.color("black")
pb.pendown()
pb.goto(350, 0)
```

I recommend that you look at the [turtle doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html), starting with the sample on the upper right, and the turtledemo module (`python -m turtledemo` or `import turtledemo`).  Also, get a few lines right before writing so much.